# Text-davinci-003 api pricing?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-3

I am using the text-davinci-003 model in Python.

```
response = openai.Completion.create(
     engine="text-davinci-003",
     prompt=question,
     max_tokens=100
)
```

I am finding the amount of tokens via: `print(response.usage.total_tokens)`. I cannot find for the life of me the pricing for `text-davinci-003 model`, only some forum I read that it is `0.0120 / 1000k tokens`. so based on this calculation, for my most recent request at `403` tokens, I should be being charged `0.004884` for the request. however, when I go into my billing dashboard, I see it went up by `1 cent`. just trying to figure out the total cost. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [OpenAI website](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/instructgpt-models), the `text-davinci-003` model is $0.02 per 1000 tokens, which is quite in line with what you've been billed. Note that the model will become deprecated on January 04, 2024.

I found the pricing with the Google search for `openai models pricing`, which lead me to https://openai.com/pricing, and from there I went to "Other Models" -> "Older models".

Answer (score 0):

I calculate my API costs using this formula:

```py
cost = (response.usage["prompt_tokens"] / 1000) * 0.02
```

You can replace the 2 cents with whatever the running cost is for the relevant model